# How to set a variable to a voice channel specified by a user - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new to discord.js and JavaScript in general so apologies if this is something really simple!

I'm working on a Discord bot and I'm trying to make it set a variable to a voice channel specified by the user. Currently, `ChosenChannel` remains `null`. It works if I replace `args` with the channel name directly in the code (line 8) but then it can't be changed by a user.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```js
client.on ('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'setchannel') {
        //set ChosenChannel to a channel within the current server that matches the name typed by the user (not currently working!)
        ChosenChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === args);
        //alert user if ChosenChannel is not an actual channel
        if (ChosenChannel == null) {
            message.channel.send('Unable to find channel');
        //alert user if ChosenChannel is not a voice channel
        } else if (ChosenChannel.type !== 'voice') {
            message.channel.send('That does not seem to be a voice channel');
        //otherwise, confirm that the command worked, and print the name of the channel
        } else {   
            message.channel.send('The chosen channel is: ');
            message.channel.send(ChosenChannel.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is an array, the channel's name is a string. So you'll need to convert `args` to a string by `join`ing it back by a space character.

```js
if (command == 'setchannel') {
  //set chosenChannel to a channel within the current server that matches the name typed by the user (not currently working!)
  const channelName = args.join(' ')
  const chosenChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === channelName,
  );
  //alert user if chosenChannel is not an actual channel
  if (!chosenChannel) {
    message.channel.send('Unable to find channel');
    //alert user if chosenChannel is not a voice channel
  } else if (chosenChannel.type !== 'voice') {
    message.channel.send('That does not seem to be a voice channel');
    //otherwise, confirm that the command worked, and print the name of the channel
  } else {
    message.channel.send('The chosen channel is: ');
    message.channel.send(chosenChannel.name);
  }
}
```

Actually, channel names can't have spaces, so it will be always the first element of `args`, so you could also use it like this:

```js
if (command == 'setchannel') {
  //set chosenChannel to a channel within the current server that matches the name typed by the user (not currently working!)
  const chosenChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (channel) => channel.name === args[0],
  );
  // ...
```

Comment: Something very simple indeed. Thanks so much for your help!